# Piping to awk (Bash)

Tags: awk

This code works:

```
#!bin/bash
ad="J Dt, K R, P MA
A F, E B, R VA
O T, O R, T OK
E A, P Rd, S MA
H S, B R, R MA"
byState() {
    a="$ad"
    h=$(echo "$a" | 
    sed -e 's/ MA/, Massachusetts/' | sed -e 's/ OK/, Oklahoma/' | sed -e 's/ VA/, Virginia/')
    h=$(echo "$h" | awk -F, '{print $4 ", " $0}' $* | sort)
    ... following code
    echo "$h"
}
byState
```

but if in function `byState` I replace `a="$ad"` by `a="$1"` and I call `byState "$ad"` I get
`awk: fatal: cannot open file 'J' for reading (No such file or directory)`.

Can someone explain this different behavior?

Comment: Could you please show us sample Input_file and expected output, we could try to help when question is clear.

Comment: what is your intention of using `$*` for the awk command?

Comment: There is no input_file only a string. I would like to have with `byState "$1"` the same result as with `bystate` ie

Comment: I actually meant in spite of telling us something is not working, you could let us know whole story about what you are trying to achieve with some few examples if possible so that we could try to help you.

Comment: I would like to have `Massachusetts, E A, P Rd, S, Massachusetts
 Massachusetts, H S, B R, R, Massachusetts
 Massachusetts, J Dt, K R, P, Massachusetts
 Oklahoma, O T, O R, T, Oklahoma
 Virginia, A F, E B, R, Virginia` and unfortunately there is not much room to give examples. The aim is to get "$ad" to be ordered by states.

Comment: If you just want to sort by a particular field you don't need to copy it to the beginning of the line, `sort` can sort by a noninitial field. But that's not even close to the question you asked.

Comment: @user3166747 there is plenty of room to give examples but you should [edit] your question to provide them, not try to provide them in comments.

Answer (score 2):

`awk -F, '{script}' $*` within function `byState()` takes the arguments of the function after wordsplitting and globbing and uses them as arguments to `awk`, and `awk` treats arguments (other than first when used as the script, and any of the form name=value which are treated as assignments) as filenames to process, which starts by opening them. Since the first token is `J` and apparently you don't have a file named `J` in the current directory opening it gives an error.

---

If you want to use the data in the first argument of `byState()` as the input to `awk`, do

```
 echo "$1" | awk -F, '{script}' # with NO OTHER ARGS to awk
```

or better

```
 printf '%s\n' "$1" | ...
 # which reliably won't mangle backslashes and some dashes
```

or even better on shells that support it (you didn't identify yours)

```
awk -F, '{script}' <<<"$1"
```

---

Also, `awk` can do string substitution without any `sed`, although if you want sed you can do multiple substitutions in one `sed`. Plus some shells can do string substitution on their own without either `sed` or `awk` -- but you didn't ask about doing this right, only what you were doing wrong.

Comment: I understand what you are saying (and that I am a beginner...) but why the code works in the first case and not in the second case. Data is the same in each case. I didn't ask about doing it right because I'm afraid somebody will tell me he is not there to do my work:-)

Comment: I think I solved it by replacing `echo "$h"` by `printf '%s' "$h" | ...`, thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3166747 that has absolutely nothing to do with the problem you're having and introduces a NEW problem because `echo "$h"` outputs a line that ends in a newline which is a valid POSIX text line, whereas `printf '%s' "$h"` outputs text with no trailing newline which subsequent tools may or may not handle "correctly" since text without a terminating newline is not valid per POSIX and so you're relying on undefined behavior. Your original problem is simply that you stuck `$*` at the end of the awk command for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I tried also with `echo` and at the same time removed the `$*` and it worked too. Nevertheless I don't yet understand why the code worked in the first case and not in the second one:-( Thanks for your post.

Comment: @user3166747: as I said in my first section and EdMorton repeated, your problem was the `$*` which told `awk` to treat the tokens of your data, beginning with `J`, as a list of filenames to be processed.